# ColdFusion chr() does not work with high ascii numbers

Tags: coldfusion, ascii, coldfusion-8, cfml

I am trying to use a cent sign in my ColdFusion program.  It appears to be ascii 155.  The function Chr() only interprets values up to 127, although the documentation says otherwise.  I found a clue in that I may need to enable high ascii characters in the ColdFusion administrator, but I could not find a place to do that.  This codes works:

```
<cfset x = Chr(127)>
<cfoutput>  this is what you get with #x# </cfoutput>
```

I get a nice box.  But this returns only a blank:

```
<cfset x = Chr(155)>
<cfoutput>  this is what you get with #x# </cfoutput>
```

How do I get Chr() working with higher numbers?

Answer (score 2):

The "cent sign" is `¢`, which is `chr(162)` (which works fine) or `&cent;` as a HTML entity.

If you want the `›` symbol then use `chr(8250)` or `&rsaquo;`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the standard american ascii chr that we are all used to, and coldfusion chr numbering do not match up.
According to the Livedocs (version 8)

> ColdFusion MX: Changed Unicode support: ColdFusion supports the Java UCS-2 representation of Unicode characters, up to a value of 65535. (Earlier releases supported 1-255.)

If you look here, this blog shows some of CF's and the HTML equiv... so you can find some of them more easily.
[cf and html entities](http://www.cjboco.com/blog.cfm/post/table-of-ascii-characters-and-symbols-for-coldfusion/)

Out of interest, i made a simple loop, and thought i'd look through them, and there are plenty of chars... the hard part is finding the right one. 
162 is a cent though, as stated in another answer, but this might help explain why.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="10000">
<pre>Chr #i# = #chr(i)#</pre>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Java UCS-2 has lots of weird characters, as you can see here.

Some Sample output:
Chr 2922 = ୪
Chr 2923 = ୫
Chr 2924 = ୬
Chr 2925 = ୭
Chr 2926 = ୮
Chr 2927 = ୯
Chr 2928 = ୰
Chr 2929 = ୱ
Chr 3207 = ಇ
Chr 3208 = ಈ
Chr 3209 = ಉ
Chr 3210 = ಊ
Chr 3211 = ಋ
Chr 3212 = ಌ